# Different result when used the date filter in WHERE and calculated metrics with SQL

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I'd like to calculate the year-to-date data (from 1st January until today-1) for example, because today is 14-11-22, so it will count start from 01-01-22 until 13-11-22.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN 
                    DATEPART(Year, booking_date ) = Datepart(Year, GETDATE()) AND 
                    DATEPART(Month, booking_date ) <= DATEPART(Month, Getdate()) AND
                    DATEPART(Day, booking_date ) < DATEPART(Day, Getdate()) THEN 
                    booking_date END) as "YearToDate" 
FROM booking_table
```

To double-check the result, I created a different query to count the data using WHERE filter:

```
SELECT count(booking_date)
FROM prod.booking_table
WHERE booking_date >= '2022-01-01 00:00:00.000000'
  AND booking_date < '2022-11-14 00:00:00.000000'
```

Unfortunately, these queries produce different results with a significant difference. I believe my query logic is correct, but I'm not sure which data part is missing from my calculation.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: what do you expect from last query?its may be related to the query date value in condition or the data you have,pls share your data

Answer (score 2):

If today is the 1st, your condition

```
AND DATEPART(Day, booking_date ) < DATEPART(Day, Getdate())
```

will filter out every day, independent of the month.

You only meant to filter by day if the month is the same (otherwise, the day doesn't matter), you can e.g. do it with

```
 DATEPART(Year, booking_date ) = Datepart(Year, GETDATE()) AND 
 DATEPART(Month, booking_date ) <= DATEPART(Month, Getdate()) AND
 (DATEPART(Day, booking_date ) < DATEPART(Day, Getdate()) OR 
  DATEPART(Month, booking_date ) < DATEPART(Month, Getdate()))
```

Nevertheless, I would suggest to just use your 2nd query.